# how to use dynamic variable insted of sheet name in vba

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic-variables

Every day i need to link today's opening balance to previous day's closing balance ,i have recorded a macro like this

```
    Range("D5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='27.07.18'!RC[6]"
Range("D5").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D5:E5"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("D5:E5").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D5:E86"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("D5:E86").Select
Range("D82").Select
```

This does the work but every day i have to chance a file name to today's date (as date is my sheet name )

Can i Use a Variable Insted Of Sheet name in FormulaR1C1

Comment: Yes, you can :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Dim s As String
s = Format$(DATE,"dd.mm.yy")
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='" & s &"'!RC[6]"
```

Assumes that the sheet already exists with this name. Otherwise first you need

```
Sheets.Add
Activesheet.Name = s
```

And you need to have the ActiveCell actually reference the original cell as the newly added sheet would have shifted this.

***Note:** If previous day please use `s = Format$(DATE-1,"dd.mm.yy")`

Comment: *... to previous day's closing balance..* I think OP wants the previous day, so `s = Format$(DATE-1,"dd.mm.yy")`, but I could be wrong. Anyways, your code is good :)

Comment: Oops! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could base it on a string var.

```
dim ws1 as string, ws2 as string

ws1 = "26.07.18"
ws2 = "27.07.18"

with worksheets(ws2)
    .Range("D5:E86").FormulaR1C1 = "='" & ws1 & "'!RC[6]"
end with
```

Perhaps you are adding a worksheet to the end of the queue every day.

```
with worksheets(worksheets.count)
    .Range("D5:E86").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='" & worksheets(worksheets.count-1).name & "'!RC[6]"
end with
```